# Complete set of punctuation marks for Python (not just ASCII)

Tags: python, string, unicode

Is there a listing or library that has all punctuations that we might commonly come across?

Normally I use `string.punctuation`, but some punctuation characters are not included in it, for example:

```
>>> "'" in string.punctuation
True
>>> "’" in string.punctuation
False
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to strip punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string)

Comment: @airstrike no not at all.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You might do better with this check:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.category("'").startswith("P")
True
>>> unicodedata.category("’").startswith("P")
True
```

The Unicode categories **P*** are specifically for **Punctuation**:

*connector (Pc), dash (Pd), initial quote (Pi), final quote (Pf), open (Ps), close (Pe), other (Po)*

To prepare the exhaustive collection, which you can subsequently use for fast membership checks, use a set comprehension:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from unicodedata import category
>>> codepoints = range(sys.maxunicode + 1)
>>> punctuation = {c for i in codepoints if category(c := chr(i)).startswith("P")}
>>> "'" in punctuation
True
>>> "’" in punctuation
True
```

[Assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) here requires Python 3.8+, equivalent for older Python versions:

```
chrs = (chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode + 1))
punctuation = set(c for c in chrs if category(c).startswith("P"))
```

Beware that some of the other characters in `string.punctuation` are actually in Unicode category **Symbol**. It's easy to add those in also if you want.

Comment: A reasonable definition of “punctuation” would include the Unicode “Symbol” categories Sc (currency, like `$`), Sk (modifier, like `^`), Sm (math, like `+` or `<`), and maybe So (other, like `©`).

Comment: @dan04 That's what the last para of the answer is mentioning about. Of course others can adapt this code to include/exclude categories depending on their own use case.

Answer (score 18):

[The answer posted by wim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60983873/2011147) is correct if you want to check if a character is a punctuation character.

If you really need a list of all punctuation characters as your question title suggests, you can use the following:

```
import sys
from unicodedata import category
punctuation_chars =  [chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) 
                             if category(chr(i)).startswith("P")]
```

Answer (score 2):

[The answer by wim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983836/complete-set-of-punctuation-marks-for-python-not-just-ascii/60983873#60983873) is great if you can change your code to use a function.

But if you have to use the `in` operator (for example, you're calling into library code), you can use duck typing:

```py
import unicodedata
class DuckType:
    def __contains__(self,s):
        return unicodedata.category(s).startswith("P")
punct=DuckType()
#print("'" in punct,'"' in punct,"a" in punct)
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a pretty job for a regular expression (regexp):

```
    import re
    text = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", str(text), flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Here, the regexp is matching everything except whitespaces or word characters. The flag `re.UNICODE` is used to match over full set of Unicode characters.

Comment: doesn't work with many languages: `>>> text="Den som dræber - fanget"
>>> re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", str(text), flags=re.UNICODE)
'Den som dr\xc3ber  fanget'`

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 What do you mean it doesn't work? It does work in your example (the `\xc3` escape is a representation thing unrelated to the stripping of punctuation).

Comment: @lenz `\xc3` is not the correct Unicode encoding of `æ`; if you type `str(text)` you can confirm that it is `\xc3\xa6`. Actually `\xc3` does not seem to be a complete codepoint.

Comment: Oh I see. It seems you both are using Python 2, where `str` is a byte string. You should definitely switch to Python 3, because Unicode is a nightmare in Py2. For me, `str('æ')` shows as `'æ'`, and `ascii('æ')` shows as `'\xe6'`, which is the correct codepoint. `b'\xc3\xa6'` is the UTF-8 encoding of `'æ'`, but this isn't usually what you want to work with.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, the way to do this is via Unicode properties/categories. [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60983873/1826241) accesses this information via the standard library `unicodedata` module, but depending on the context where you need this, it might be faster or more convenient to access this same property information using regular expressions.

However, the standard library [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) does not provide extended Unicode support. For that, you need the [`regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), available on PyPI (`pip install regex`):

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> re.match("\p{Punctuation}", "'")
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match="'">
>>> re.match("\p{Punctuation}", "’")
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='’'>
```

A good overview of all the different kinds of Unicode properties you can search for using regular expressions is provided [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). Apart from these extra regular expression features, which are documented on its PyPI homepage, `regex` deliberately provides the same API as `re`, so you're expected to use `re`'s documentation to figure out how to use either of them.